# $_POST - results to be sent in a email

Tags: php

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="70" name="filename" id="result" style="background:#B0D2D7;
width:100%;overflow:auto;resize:none"
readonly><?php echo $_POST['filename']; ?></textarea>
```

Hi all, this is a snippet of code I'm using. What I'm struggling with is how to send
the `$_POST` results that get displayed on the next page into an email using PHP email.
The results are not displayed in a text box as such on the next page but displayed more like a `print_pr` into a PHP form.
Any help would be great!

Comment: what exactly are you struggling with? Do you have mail code already and it's not working?

Comment: Thanks for the Google, I have the email etc setup and working just can not get the output of the `$_POST` to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move data across into another page via `POST`, the easiest way is to wrap your `textarea` in a form and add a submit button:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
    <textarea name="filename"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["filename"]))
    {
        echo $_POST["filename"];
    }
?>
```

You also made a vague reference to sending an email, which can be done using the [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

Comment: OK Cheers all, I'll a have quick play around and be back with results.

Comment: @Marty.W. The data already moves across to a next page and is displayed as text not in a text area as such. I can email the results if the results are manually pasted into the PHP form text boxes. I would like to just email the results that are displayed as text on the next page. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
<? 
$g_mail = "mail@domain.com"; 
$s_name = "Some name"; 
$to = "Receiver <receiver@domain.com>";    
$subject = "Some subject";  

$message= "HTML codes here. Write anything you want including " . $_POST['data']; 

$header = "From: $s_name <".$g_mail.">\n";  
$header .= "Reply-To: $s_name <".$g_mail.">\n"; 
$header .= "Return-Path: $s_name <".$g_mail.">\n";   
$header .= "Delivered-to:  $s_name <".$g_mail.">\n"; 
$header .= "Date: ".date(r)."\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-9\n";    
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$header .= "Importance: Normal\n"; 
$header .= "X-Sender: $s_name <".$g_mail.">\n";    
$header .= "X-Priority: 3\n";    
$header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n"; 
$header .= "X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook, Build 11.0.5510\n"; 
$header .= "X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2900.2869\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header); 
?>
```

This is the mail script I generally use. It will not be marked as spam on most mail providers aswell.

Comment: Using `<?`, the OP would have to have short tags "on".

Comment: what happens if `mail()` fails?